# Searching for specific key value in array of structs and returning struct

Tags: coldfusion

I can be a bit confused sometimes between arrays and structures. However, I think I understand correctly now that my data below is technically an array of structures (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
<cfset Contacts = [
  {
    ID = "1",
    CompanyName = "Company One",
    FirstName = "Elliott",
    LastName = "Smith",
    ...etc...
  },
  {
    ID = "2",
    CompanyName = "Company Two",
    FirstName = "Matthew",
    LastName = "Ryan",
    ...etc...
  }
]>
```

I would like to search this data by ID (2, for example) and return the rest of that structure's data (CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, etc...).

How can I do this? (If my data is not in a searchable format, please let me know how I can change it so it is.)

Thank you!

Comment: I know it would be much easier if this data were in a database, but in this scenario I cannot do that.

Comment: Yes, it is an array of structures. AFAIK, the only way is to loop through the array elements and check the individual `id` values for a match. That said, if you need to access the elements by a specific key, then storing them in a structure might be better. (Unless you need to maintain a specific order)

Comment: _If my data is not in a searchable format, please let me know how I can change it so it is._  You could create your own query record set from the data.  Then use SQL to run queries against it.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_20.html

Comment: Do you need to search the elements by multiple keys? (If yes, ignore my previous suggestion). How many elements are you talking about?

Comment: @Leigh: Thanks. I believe I can handle this. I'm only searching for one unique ID in the ID key. There are ~50 structures, but could be more.

Comment: @Miguel-F: Thanks for your suggestion, I've heard of this, and will look into this technique regardless. The data needs to stay in a fairly user-friendly format, which is why I chose to throw it in an array of structures. (Easy to edit, and I threw it in its own separate file.) I suppose I could leave it there, then loop over it and put it in a query record, but if I'm going to loop over it I figure I might as well just check for the value then. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Michael - Well, without knowing more, it is hard to say what is the best approach (other than the obvious suggestion of using a database - typically the superior choice). However, if order is not important, then it is better to store them in structure, by `id`. Then you could avoid unnecessary looping and just do lookups by key.

Comment: @Leigh: Order is not important. How would I store them in one structure? (What's the difference in syntax from what I have above?) And then what function would I use to look-up by key? Thanks again!

Comment: (Edit) @Michael - Use a nested structure. The syntax is essentially the same, just use the ids `1,2,...` as the keys ie `<cfset data = { firstKey = {ID=1, CompanyName="..."}, secondKey ={ID=2, CompanyName="..."} } />`.  Keep in mind you might store the data differently. For example, store it as JSON - then deserialize it when loaded into CF.  Just be aware the file storage approach is not scalable... Out of curiosity, why can't you use a database for this?

Comment: You guys are gonna hate me. The reason I couldn't use a database is because I'm primarily a front-end dev and the back-end dev (my manager) holds all the keys to the database. The original project scope was much simpler and I was told to hard-code the contacts (exhibitors, in this case) on the page to save time. I've since applied a bit more pressure after the scope change to give me a new table to work with. So I have the data in a database now and I'm all set. HOWEVER, your efforts are not in vain because I have run into this exact issue before with other types of data.

Comment: Sometimes, if I don't have the necessary data already available to me in a query, it helps me to use a structure and loop through that so I can present a proof of concept for the front-end. Thanks again for your help. I'd like to give points for the answer to Leigh for the answer I would have chosen if not for getting it in a table. If not I'll mark Mag's also helpful comment as correct.

Comment: *You guys are gonna hate me.* Not at all. The important part is you are on a much better path using the db route. Keep in mind, you can always use `queryNew` to mock up a db query in a pinch. BTW: Feel free to go with Mag's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Leigh's suggestion is a good one. Because you'll already have the data in memory at this point looping through an array even if it's pretty large will be fast. I like using CFScript for this type of task. Here's a working example using part of the data you provided:

```
<cfscript>
    // array of structs version
    contacts = [{
        ID = "1",
        CompanyName = "Company One",
        FirstName = "Elliott",
        LastName = "Smith"
    },{
        ID = "2",
        CompanyName = "Company Two",
        FirstName = "Matthew",
        LastName = "Ryan"
    }];

    for(i=1; i <= arrayLen(contacts); i++) {
        if (contacts[i]['id'] EQ '2') {
            writeoutput(contacts[i]['CompanyName'] & '<br />');
            writeoutput(contacts[i]['FirstName'] & '<br />');
            writeoutput(contacts[i]['LastName'] & '<br />');
            break;
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

**Update:**

Here is another version using a struct of structs:

```
<cfscript>
    contact1 = {
        CompanyName = "Company One",
        FirstName = "Elliott",
        LastName = "Smith"
    };

    contact2 = {
        CompanyName = "Company Two",
        FirstName = "Matthew",
        LastName = "Ryan"
    };

    contacts = {
        1=contact1,
        2=contact2
    };

    contact_struct=structfind(contacts,'2');

    outstr = '';
    outstr = outstr & contact_struct['CompanyName'] & '<br />';
    outstr = outstr & contact_struct['FirstName'] & '<br />';
    outstr = outstr & contact_struct['LastName'] & '<br />';

    writeoutput(outstr);

</cfscript>
```

Comment: Actually based on later comments, I think a structure of structures would be better in this case. Then there is no need for looping. Just a simple lookup by key. (Small tip: unless the array can contain duplicate id's, you typically want to `break;` out of the for loop once a matching value is found, since there is nothing more to do.)

Comment: OK added a second example with a **struct of structs** version and added break; to the first. I'll be curious to know what works out!

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful to see it in an example.

Comment: I usually go with `<cfif structKeyExists(...)>`, then grab the value with structure  notation. Just to avoid the exception thrown by `structFind` if the key does not exist for some reason. Just personal preference though :)